# Telnet "invalid message format"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, telnet

I started a local Telnet server that listens on port 5555.

```
~$ telnet localhost 5555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello
Invalid message format
```

Telnet was started from a web application, which I started by SBT. [Read here.](https://livebook.manning.com/book/reactive-web-applications/chapter-7/210) Look up text `telnet localhost`. I think they meant that this command should be run from the command line, as I did. However they do get the input returned as expected.

As you can see, I typed "Hello"... and was supposed to get back the input ("Hello")?

But instead I am getting "Invalid message format".

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Your `Hello` got to some program; then `Invalid message format` came from the program. Telnet was just an *interface* connecting your terminal to the program and it seems it worked fine. It's the program who complained. Whether or not `Hello` is a valid message, and whether or not you should get the input back – it all depends on the program. So what is the program that listens on port `5555`? And why do you believe it should accept `Hello` and return `Hello`? Please [edit] and add this information to the question body.

Comment: You are right. I think telnet was started from a web application, which I started by SBT. Read here https://livebook.manning.com/book/reactive-web-applications/chapter-7/210 Look up text `telnet localhost`. I think they meant that this command should be run from the command line, as I did. However they do get the input returned as expected.